# Validating and processing form blocks

Tags: php, html, forms, content-management-system

I'm in the process of building a CMS for myself. I have never built a CMS from the ground up before, and I really do not want to use Wordpress or an equivalent.

My goal here is to create a form page that updates several other pages. Which I have succeeded except for the mater of time and having numerous process.php files to process each form seperately is time consuming for my self and I could not imagine being a user.

I have searched however have not found anything similar enough to manipulate or get ideas from to solve my problem. What Im looking at is a mass multiform process (if that is possible?) to speed up the process. What I've read so far is to make it just one form block with the same action. This is exactly where I want to go but do not understand exactly how to process at once and divide it into according chunks in one form.

Below is a sample of a form block. This is one of 4 blocks that are ALMOST identical the differentiating value is the hidden value.

```
<form action="xboxtopratedprocess.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p><h3>Xbox 360</h3>
                <!-- title of post/ game name -->
                <p><label for="title"> Title of Game </lable></p>
                <input type="text" name="title" size=20 /><br />

                <!-- image uploader -->
                <p><label for="image">Game Image:</label><sup>*png, png, bmp, jpeg and jpg only!</sup></p>
                <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                <!-- large text box -->
                <p><label for="text">Displayed text:</label><sup> * limit of 250 characters allowed.</sup></p>
                <textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="message"></textarea>

                <input type="hidden" name="system" value="xbox">
                <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" /></p>


                </p>
            </form>
```

The general idea of the form is to give a picture a description of the game and the title of the game as well as the system type.

When this form is processed it is uploaded to a mysql database and stores the values to re post. Which all works dandy if I process one at a time; separately with different processes even though the only different values are the "system" value and the process.php for each form block.

Where I want to go with this is one giant form one giant process.
I am not looking for the exact solution here and I do not expect one.

However, what I'd like to know is:
a)Is it possible to submit multiple blocks of forms at once?
ii) if so, can a block like above be used?/ what needs to be added to make it possible.
b)If I used the block above and 4 times on one page with different hidden values How can i differentiate them so that I could handle each gaming system separately and form there can be broken down to each database? (I already have the breakdown, storage, and page posting)

Comment: .. name="message[]" .. etc will create an array you can loop through

Comment: Please, please, just ask the question to start with :)

Comment: Never mind I found the answer to my questions here.
http://bavotasan.com/2009/processing-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-php/

very simple Sharing the link incase anyone else has this problem in the future.

Comment: such mess to describe the "can i have FOO number of forms in a page and handle their responses in the same php file?"